# There are times so that class must "default copy c'tor" ? and what is happens while I doing "new Type[..]"?

Tags: c++, c++11

What happens in the following line:

```
Type* arr=new Type[20];
```

the type `Type` must `copy constructor` or `default constructor` or `default copy constructor`?

And again, which method is called in this line ?

Comment: It must supply a default constructor. So don't wriite code like that, use a std::vector. And why the heck are we suddenly having all these questions on this subject?

Comment: @NeilButterworth But it's not really give me answer about the question. You only said what can I do , but not why it's happens like that..

Comment: It happens like that because there is no way to supply constructor arguments to each member of such dynamic array. Use `vector`

Comment: With a vector, you can create a copy of an initialized object, `std::vector<Type>(20, Type(...))` which will create 20 copies of the default value supplied

Comment: You must supply a default constructor

Comment: @smac89 well, you can write an explicit brace-initializer with the right number of elements, but why bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

```
 Type* arr=new Type[20];
```

then enough memory to contain 20 objects of type `Type`. is allocated. The default constructor for `Type` is then called 20 times to construct each of those `Type` instances. If there is no default constructor for `Type`, (as there won't be if you defined some other constructor) then these instances cannot be constructed.

The `std::vector` container doesn't have this restriction, as you can either provide parameters for its initialisation, or create objects on the fly and push them into the `std::vector` after the vector is created. This is one of many reasons why you should always prefer use of `std::vector` over allocating arrays via `new`.